# Python keeps giving an error when execute sql request

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

In this case, this project was writen on `python 3.4`, works with `mysql`(especially uses `pymysql` library). Getting this error while execute sql request: **`mysql error sql: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 8 bytes`**. It tries to execute the sql query below:

```
sql = """
        SELECT n.name
        FROM %s n
        WHERE n.ID = %d """ % (globals.tbl_notification_type, notificationTypeID)
```

Anybody came accross simular problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace %d with %s:

```
sql = """
    SELECT n.name
    FROM %s n
    WHERE n.ID = %s """ % (globals.tbl_notification_type, notificationTypeID)
```